# How to tie a deforming knot with a curve?

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm trying to make a knot that deforms realistically using a beveled curve. It should look something like this:

[image]

This is what I have so far, and these are my curve settings:

[image]

[image]

How could I achieve this using the curve and avoiding converting to a mesh?

Thanks!

Comment: You can adjust the [radius](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/curves/properties/introduction.html#radius) to shrink the bevel at a point but to deform the surface so it looks like it is scrunched up will have to be done with a mesh.

Comment: Ah I figured thanks.  Is there a way you would suggest for modeling once it's been converted to mesh?